# Compiling codes with *_s in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: string, visual-c++, stdio

I'm trying to compile some old codes in Visual C++ 6.0. The DSW file was missing, so I'm adding all the codes into a new workspace.

I have `a.cpp` as follows

```
#include "vld.h"
#include "afx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"

...

void function_1(char* string1)
{
   char buf[2000];
   strcpy_s(&buf[0], 2000, string1);
   strcat_s(&buf[0], 2000, "_append");
   ...
}
```

There are other functions used such as `fopen_s, strncpy_s, strncat_s` in `a.cpp` as well.

And `b.h` is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char function_2(unsigned char * string2, int abc, int def)
{
   char buf2[200];
   sprintf_s(buf2, 200, "abcdef");
   strcat_s(buf2, 200, "ghijkl");
}
```

Despite already having `stdio.h` and `string.h`, I still get the errors

```
'sprintf_s': undeclared identifier
'strcat_s': undeclared identifier
'strcpy_s': undeclared identifier
'fopen_s': undeclared identifier
'strncpy_s': undeclared identifier
'strncat_s': undeclared identifier
```

for both `a.cpp` and `b.h`.

Is there any missing settings that I've left out? Why am I getting these errors?

Comment: Rather than passing `200` or `2000` directly, you should pass `sizeof buf` and `sizeof buf2`. This will mean that if you change the size of the array, all of the string functions will automatically operate on the new size. This only works as long as `buf` and `buf2` are array types. This won't work for example, if they are declared as `char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _s version function were added to  Visual Studio 2005. So you need use more modern Visual Studio version.